# Retrieve data from themoviedb API

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I want to get all movies from themoviedb api, I tried using popular movies

Which by default return 20 movies per page ,

Here is my route for getting popular movies

```
/* GET movies listing. */
router.get('/movies', function(req, res, next) {
  request('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?&sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=2931998c3a80d7806199320f76d65298', function(error, rensponse, body){
  res.send(body)
  });
});
```

I tried differnt combination but nothing worked,  right now only one page displays with just 20 movies,

How can I access and display the rest of the pages something like page1, pag2, page3 in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know **`No`** there is not way. You'll have to query however many pages/items you want to display.

I know you can query for a specific page but that doesn't really help since there is no way of knowing how many pages there are for a specific movie

Each paginated response contains a total_pages and total_items field so you can easily build proper pagination into your app.

Related **[`reference`](https://www.themoviedb.org/talk/55aa2a76c3a3682d63002fb1)**.